# Overwrite SharePoint file without loosing it's version history

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

I have a need to overwrite a SharePoint file content in a library but keep the version history as is.

PnP.Core `context.Site.CreateCopyJobsAsync` promised to do that but it does not.

Also `IFile.MoveToAsync(destinationUrl,...`  overwrites the version History.

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I know that CSOM `Site.CreateCopyJob` method has a parameter `options` of type `CopyMigrationOptions` with a property `IgnoreVersionHistory`.

According [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/spod-copy-move-api#spcopymigrationoptions): if not specified, the version history will be ignored and not moved to the destination.

Comment: I tried that but it resets the target's version history which I want to preserve